# PowerShell throwing a 400 bad request. Any suggestions?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I used this script to pull any user who hasn't signed in for the last 30 days and export a .csv. This has worked for months and suddenly stopped working. The error is:

Invoke-WebRequest: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$ApplicationID = "Application ID placeholder"
$TenatDomainName = "Tenant placeholder"
$AccessSecret = "Access secret placeholder"
$SignInDate = Get-Date -Date (Get-Date).Date.addDays(-30) -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"`

$Body = @{    
Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"
Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
client_Id     = $ApplicationID
Client_Secret = $AccessSecret
} 

$ConnectGraph = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenatDomainName/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $Body

$token = $ConnectGraph.access_token

$Users = Invoke-MSCloudIdMSGraphQuery -AccessToken $Token -GraphQuery "beta/users?filter=signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime le $SignInDate" | Where-Object userPrincipalName -like '*@placeholder.uk' | Select displayName,userPrincipalName,onPremisesSamAccountName | Export-CSV C:\temp\AZusersinactive.csv
```

I've checked the certificates and access secrets in Azure app registrations and everything appears to be in order. Any ideas about what might have changed?

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: **`signInActivity`** doesn't support filters for  date operations. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta).

When I executed the script I got the same error like below:

```bash
$ApplicationID = "Application ID placeholder"
$TenatDomainName = "Tenant placeholder"
$AccessSecret = "Access secret placeholder"
$SignInDate = Get-Date -Date (Get-Date).Date.addDays(-30) -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"`

$Body = @{    
Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"
Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
client_Id     = $ApplicationID
Client_Secret = $AccessSecret
} 

$ConnectGraph = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenatDomainName/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $Body

$token = $ConnectGraph.access_token

$Users = Invoke-MSCloudIdMSGraphQuery -AccessToken $Token -GraphQuery "beta/users?filter=signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime le $SignInDate" | Where-Object userPrincipalName -like '*@placeholder.uk' | Select displayName,userPrincipalName,onPremisesSamAccountName | Export-CSV C:\temp\AZusersinactive.csv
```

[image]

**Hence**, as a workaround make use of below PowerShell script:

```bash
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "AuditLog.Read.All"
Select-MgProfile -Name "beta"

$users= get-mguser -Property DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, SignInActivity, UserType
$users | Where-Object {($_.SignInActivity.LastSignInDateTime -le $((Get-Date).AddDays(-30))) -and ($_.UserType -eq "Member")}
```

***I got the users who hasn't signed in for the last 30 days successfully:***

[image]

**References:**

[Microsoft Graph Rest API - Filter by last X days - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73694642/microsoft-graph-rest-api-filter-by-last-x-days) by user2250152

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there a way I can incorporate this into the script I already have? The script is automated so there's no user input and the credentials are handled via the body.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to do  incorporate this into your script.